# Bootstrap - Going from basic template to more advanced examples

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I think this may be offtopic but I don't know how else to ask it or where else to direct it. I'm a new web developer and I'm used to building CSS and HTML from scratch to make various tools. I wanted to make a move into a framework like Bootstrap to make things look a little more professional but I'm really struggling to understand how to use it.

I'm struggling to understand the file structure bootstrap provides and where it should live in my web server. The basic minified download consists of folders for css, fonts and js. However examples such as the jumbotron reference other files such as

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
```

But I don't know where these files are supposed to live. Do I need to modify each of these href links? What should the file structure look like?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I dont think you need all of those...Simply add the minified css of bootstrap, jquery and then minified js of bootstrap and you are good to go...You can go here and create a sample template: http://www.initializr.com/

Comment: @Navnit, Wish I knew this existed. Was very helpful

Comment: happy to help.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the latest version of bootstrap [getting started guide](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) you will be able to understand the folder structure.

Bootstrap has separated out the different type of files into different folders.

```
bootstrap/
        ├── css/
        │   ├── bootstrap.css
        │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
        │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
        │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
        │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
        │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
        │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
        │   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
        ├── js/
        │   ├── bootstrap.js
        │   └── bootstrap.min.js
        └── fonts/
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

JS file is needed in case you want to use the plugins provided by Bootstrap. if you dont want to use any [plugins](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) then you dont have to include js file.

in your example above , first file is obvious that its a bootstrap.css file. second file is fix for ie, some feature of bootstrap doesn't work in ie10. Third file is application specific file. and 4th one is for debugging purpose as said in the comments.

if you are using bower or some other tool for dependency management then all your third party dependencies should go eaither in `bower_components` or vendor folder. all you application specific css should reside in your app folder.

hope it helps.